# Can I open a file in Java that is in a user's home directory on Windows Enterprise with Active Directory?

Tags: java, file-io, active-directory

I have a program that puts some information in a user's My Documents folder.  I find this folder by using System.getProperty("user.home");  Now I have a customer for whom this doesn't work and when I got some debug output from him the file name it tried to access was in the form \name.com\HHA\Users\person\My Documents\file.txt.  Is this related to active directory?  Or some other weirdness?

Answer (score 0):

try using **JfileChooser**

```
new JFileChooser().getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory();
```

**instead of**

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

i doubt it returns proper home directory

Comment: This returns the same thing (with the addition of "My Documents").  The problem is Java.io.File does not recognize this as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

ok then please try this..

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Documents");`

Do notice double back slash and take care while using code..!!
and ya you can change the path as per your config.!!

Thanks.